# Map to method c++11

Tags: c++, function, c++11, dictionary, pointer-to-member

I'm tried to make a map to class methods using C++11's `function`.

The C-Style function pointers:

Method:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(void*);
```

Map declare:

```
std::map<int, void (MyClass::*)(void*)> mapIdToMethod;
```

Map insert:

```
mapIdToMethod.insert(std::make_pair(2, &MyClass::MyMethod));
```

Method call:

```
MyClass mc;
(mc.*mapIdToMethod.at(1))(nullptr);
```

**The code above is worked, But how can I convert it to use C++11's `function`?**

What i'm tried:
Map declare:

```
std::map<int, function<void(void*)>> mapIdToMethod;//The map declare
```

Now, how can I insert and call the method on this `map`?

Comment: if there aren't any problems with the code as you have it, leave it at that. **If it ain't broken, don't fix it**

Comment: std::function is a different thing. your original code only stores the member function pointers. std::function would require that the member function pointer was bound to an instance of the class.

Comment: if the function MyMethod uses some internal state, you probably need to [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) it, or use lambda. But as @bolov said, you shouldn't modify it if it works. At least because std::function places runtime overhead on it, so just leave it be.

Comment: Two maps you've presented here server completely different purposes. One holds pointers-to-member-function, which require the instance to be called; the other is a container for fully-bound function objects. Do you want to store bound functions instead in your new approach?

Comment: Give an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm guessing this map is used for something like windows `Window Procedure`?

Comment: This is valid c++11, so your conversion is done :) But seriously, why do you want to change it? It accomplishes the goal perfectly as it is.

Comment: @StoryTeller One obvious reason to change to `function<void(void*)>` is so the value of the `map` can also contain other non-member function pointers, or lambdas.

Comment: @JonathanMee, is it? It's not a requirement from what I gather. Why incur overhead for something that we don't need!?

Comment: @StoryTeller To be fair, Evyatar hasn't told us why he wants `function<void(void*)>` values. I'm just explaining that there are things that `function<void(void*)>` can do that `void (*)(void*)` cannot.

Comment: @bolov The current `map` only accepts member functions. To expand the functionality to also accept lambdas *and* non-member function pointers a value type of `function<void(void*)>` makes sense.

Comment: `mapIdToMethod.insert(std::make_pair(2, &MyClass::MyMethod));` can be rewritten as `mapIdToMethod.emplace(2, &MyClass::MyMethod);` in c++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also a fan of `function` over C-style pointers, but it's important that you recognize that the analog for `void (MyClass::*)(void*)` is `function<void(MyClass&, void*)>` *not* `function<void(void*)>`. So you could replicate what you've already have going in `MapIdToMethod` with:

```
map<int, function<void(MyClass&, void*)>> bar;
```

You could insert to this the same way as you inserted to `MapIdToMethod` (`bar.insert(make_pair(2, &MyClass::MyMethod)`), but you could also use [`mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), which wouldn't have been possible to use when inserting to `MapIdToMethod`:

```
bar.insert(make_pair(2, mem_fn(&MyClass::MyMethod)));
```

Now, to answer your question. Given:

```
map<int, function<void(void*)>> foo;
```

You can insert member functions which take a `void*` and don't return anything, *but only if you already have the object on which you wish to make the calls constructed*. You can do that using [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
MyClass mc;

foo.insert(make_pair(2, bind(&MyClass::MyMethod, mc, placeholders::_1)));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/vECrxn)

Answer (score 4):

Probably not as efficient as the original but maybe easier to read:

```
std::map<int, std::function<void (MyClass&,void*)>> mapIdToMethod;    
mapIdToMethod.emplace(2, [](MyClass& c,void* p){ c.MyMethod(p);});
// alternatively:
using std::placeholders::_1;    
using std::placeholders::_2;
mapIdToMethod.emplace(2,std::bind(&MyClass::MyMethod,_1,_2));

MyClass mc;
mapIdToMethod.at(2)(mc, nullptr);
```

Comment: No, it isn't easier to read. Definitely cool use of C++11 features, but not at all easy to read.

Comment: Given that OP has C++11, you could use `std::bind` and `std::placeholders::_1`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I agree.

Comment: `emplace` would improve readability and get rid of `std::make_pair`.